# Getting specific text from filenames in Bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to write bash script, in which I could get the specific text from all filenames in directory, e.g
I have files in my folder:

```
.\file1.txt
.\file2.hex
.\DSConf-11.22.33[4444].pkg
.\file3.cpp
```

What I need to do is taking 4444 number from above filenames. I created a script but it doesn't work and I can't find mistake:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
FILENAME=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "DSConf-*.*.*\[*\].pkg")
PATTERN='^DSConf-(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)\[([^)]+)\]'
[[ $FILENAME =~ $PATTERN ]]

echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
```

Comment: first of all, regex in bash works with `[[ STRING =~ STRING ]]` syntax. what do you expect to be your output?

Comment: I don't think `\d` works in bash. Try `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is 4444

Comment: Also, do you need `.\\` at the beginning of your pattern? Hmm or maybe it should be  ./

Comment: What about this: `find -name "DSConf*" | sed -E 's/.*\[([0-9]+)\].*/\1/'`  ?

Comment: It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in ./; do echo "$f" | grep -Eo "DSConf-\d+.\d+.\d+\[([^)]+)\]"; done
```

will generate your output.

Answer (score 0):

You may look for files with names starting with `DSConf-` and end with `.pkg` using `find -name "DSConf-*"` and then get the digits between square brackets using `sed`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "DSConf-*.pkg" | sed -n 's/.*\[\([0-9]*\)].*/\1/p'
```

The `sed -n 's/.*\[\([0-9]*\)].*/\1/p'` command suppresses sed line output using `-n`, then `s/.*\[\([0-9]*\)].*/\1/p` substitutes the whole string with just the 0 or more digits between `[` and `]` and `p` prints that number.